# How to see both sides in Skype video chatting?

Tags: ubuntu, skype

Both my friend and I have webcams on our computers. I can see him in his webcam. I would like to see me at the same time. I would like to know how to see both sides in Skype video chatting? Thanks! My OS is Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: What version of skype are you using? That is the default behavior on mine (4.0.0.8). I can see myself in a small window under the video chat and, in fact, I can see no way of deactivating it.

Comment: Mine is 4.2.0.11.

Comment: By the way, do you know if there is some online service to test webcam? I know skype has its service to test speaker.

Answer (score 1):

First off try hitting the blue button that looks like a camera and hitting "Start my video".

If this does not work you can try to reinstall Skype for Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: The OP is asking how to see _himself_ while video chatting. He has no problems starting his video feed.

Comment: @Gordon Skype by default shows your output video by default this answer is correct.

Comment: Ubuntu questions are perfectly on topic here. Please also note that [ubuntu.SE] is not a forum, it's a Q&A site.

Comment: Ubuntu questions are on topic here but ASkUbuntu has lots of Ubuntu members that go there to answer Ubuntu type questions, I was simply suggesting another site that could give good help to this question

Answer (score -2):

you need click on "video call" button then your friend needs to accept by clicking on "answer video call"

Comment: The OP is asking how to see himself while video chatting. He has no problems starting his video feed.

Comment: ok.. but what is OP?

Comment: @İncisiker "OP" stands for original poster or the author of the question.

Comment: Sorry, OP means [Original Poster](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=OP&defid=2172424), it is an internet term for the person who started a thread on a forum or the person who posted the question on SE (Stack Exchange) network pages.